# ValueError: unknown enum label "Hudi"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-hudi, dataproc

I am using dataproc 2.1 with the following software_config in a json file.

```html
"software_config": {
        "properties": {},
        "optional_components": ["JUPYTER","ZEPPELIN","Hudi"]

    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```html
[2023-12-14, 04:08:59 IST] {taskinstance.py:1851} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 609, in execute
    operation = self._create_cluster(hook)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 535, in _create_cluster
    return hook.create_cluster(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 468, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 332, in create_cluster
    result = client.create_cluster(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1/services/cluster_controller/client.py", line 534, in create_cluster
    request = clusters.CreateClusterRequest(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 516, in __init__
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 211, in to_proto
    pb_value = rule.to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 36, in to_proto
    return self._descriptor(**value)
ValueError: unknown enum label "Hudi"
```

NOTE: I tried with "HUDI" as well but still I am getting the error.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 609, in execute
    operation = self._create_cluster(hook)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 535, in _create_cluster
    return hook.create_cluster(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 468, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 332, in create_cluster
    result = client.create_cluster(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1/services/cluster_controller/client.py", line 534, in create_cluster
    request = clusters.CreateClusterRequest(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 516, in __init__
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 211, in to_proto
    pb_value = rule.to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 36, in to_proto
    return self._descriptor(**value)
ValueError: unknown enum label "HUDI"
```

Comment: `Hudi` should be `HUDI`.

Comment: I tried with HUDI as well but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: The Python client SDK lib might be too old.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can install this component to Dataproc 2.1.2+ image versions:

> You can install the Hudi component on Dataproc clusters created with the following Dataproc image versions:
>
> - 1.5.80+
> - 2.0.54+
> - 2.1.2+

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/hudi#compatible_image_versions